# Excel doesn't open in some computers

Tags: c#, excel

I have this weird behaviour with my form-application app that in some computers the excel is not created but in others it is.

The problem is related to some excel security but I haven't figure out yet where to allow excel to allow my app to create excels. I have already tried to go on: 
`Tools > Options > Trust center` and allowed everything I could but without success.

I create the excel file with this piece of code:

```
xlWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, full_path);
```

The `EXCEL.EXE` is set on Task Manager **EVEN** if the excel isn't created successfully. And I cannot open any excel instance until I end that process.

The problem is not related to any specific version since I've seen the problem in office 2010 and 2016.

Comment: You say the issue is related to security but you don’t show any error. Is there some error in particular that makes you think that? Also, are you setting the app to visible?

Comment: I think it's security related because one time an excel popup shown up to allow my app to open something and I accept it and from that on it worked.

Comment: There's no error in particular, it just creates a process called "EXCEL.EXE" on Task Manager and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you setting it to visible?

Comment: what if you right click on the application on the machines where it does not work and select `Run as Administrator`

Comment: @MethodMan Tried that before and doesn't work, the same problem behaviour occurs.

Comment: sounds like you are missing some updates for the version of VS that you have.. I know they had an update for this as well for VS2015